# How to input a path with a white space?

Tags: shell

I have a main file which uses(from the main I do a source) a properties file with variables pointing to paths.

The properties file looks like this:

```
TMP_PATH=/$COMPANY/someProject/tmp
OUTPUT_PATH=/$COMPANY/someProject/output
SOME_PATH=/$COMPANY/someProject/some path
```

The problem is `SOME_PATH`, I must use a path with spaces (I can't change it).

I tried escaping the whitespace, with quotes, but no solution so far.

I edited the paths, the problem with single quotes is I'm using another variable `$COMPANY` in the path

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Use one of these threee variants:

```
SOME_PATH="/mnt/someProject/some path"
SOME_PATH='/mnt/someProject/some path'
SOME_PATH=/mnt/someProject/some\ path
```

Comment: Yes but I had the \ escaping the space already. Wasn't saying the others were wrong.

Comment: `$ CC="/cygdrive/d/xxx yyy/cc" ; $CC` leads to `bash: /cygdrive/d/xxx: No such file or directory`. How to fix?

Comment: @pmor: `CC="/cygdrive/d/xxx yyy/cc" ; "$CC"`

Answer (score 50):

I see Federico you've found solution by yourself. 
The problem was in two places. Assignations need proper quoting, in your case

```
SOME_PATH="/$COMPANY/someProject/some path"
```

is one of possible solutions.

But in shell those quotes are not stored in a memory, 
so when you want to use this variable, you need to quote it again, for example:

```
NEW_VAR="$SOME_PATH"
```

because if not, space will be expanded to command level, like this:

```
NEW_VAR=/YourCompany/someProject/some path
```

which is not what you want.

<sub>For more info you can check out my article about it http://www.cofoh.com/white-shell</sub>

Comment: This should really be marked as the correct answer. The detail of quoting the variables themselves seems to be the main thing that trips people up (me included!)

Comment: The crucial bit of information which helped me was the fact that the quotes used during definition of the variable do not become part of the value of the variable, so the variable has to be quoted again when used.

Answer (score 22):

You can escape the "space" char by putting a \ right before it.

Comment: Did you wrap that path in any quotations by any chance?

Comment: Resolved. The problem was in one reference was the variable without the quotes

Answer (score 4):

```
SOME_PATH=/mnt/someProject/some\ path
```

should work

Comment: Yea I tried escaping the character, but in that case gives me "/mnt/someProject/some" without the " path"

Comment: It might have to do something with your OS then. A standard bash console should work. What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If the file contains only parameter assignments, you can use the following loop in place of sourcing it:

```
# Instead of source file.txt
while IFS="=" read name value; do
    declare "$name=$value"
done < file.txt
```

This saves you having to quote anything in the file, and is also more secure, as you don't risk executing arbitrary code from `file.txt`.

Comment: This could have been a solution. The problem is there are more things than assignations. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the path in Ubuntu is "/home/ec2-user/Name of Directory", then do this:

1) Java's build.properties file:

```
build_path='/home/ec2-user/Name\\ of\\ Directory'
```

Where `~/` is equal to `/home/ec2-user`

2) Jenkinsfile:

```
build_path=buildprops['build_path']
echo "Build path= ${build_path}"
sh "cd ${build_path}"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no good answer for this, there are circumstances where every combination of `\` , `' '` or even `"$VAR"` which seems to fix the issue, breaks later.

So, Avoid spaces in the path entirely:

On any unix system, you can make soft-links with `ln -s`

So do this for your badly-behaved path and then put the name of the new link (you have created somewhere with a spaceless path) into your variable instead.

This solves the case where you can't change the path.

This way the escape characters or quoting only need work for the one call to `ln -s`, probably in the same batch file you're going to `export` it.

Thereafter the variable will work, without renaming the path to the things it needs to include.