# Bash path contained space no such file or directory

Tags: bash, path, cygwin

As per this question [How to input a path with a white space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902227/how-to-input-a-path-with-a-white-space) I have declared a directory path like that:

`startup='/cygdrive/c/Users/Me/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup';` I tried to wrap the path in to double quotes but it is not working either.

But for some reason when I am typing `$startup` I am getting an error:

```
$ $startup
bash: /cygdrive/c/Users/Alex/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start: No such file or directory
```

How would u fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surround your variable with quotes:

```
$ "$startup"
```

You should always quote variables to be safe. You can refer to [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html) page for more details.

As it states in the first paragraph: *"When referencing a variable, it is generally advisable to enclose its name in double quotes. This prevents reinterpretation of all special characters within the quoted string -- except $, ` (backquote), and \ (escape)."*

You can also refer to [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) page which states: *The basic rule of thumb is that you should double-quote every expansion. This prevents unwanted word splitting and globbing. When in doubt, quote it.*

Comment: Yeah that is working but why in is not working without a quotes?

Comment: The shell performs word-splitting on the result of a parameter expansion, so you need to quote the string when you are defining it *and* when you expand it.