# Path expansion and command expansion from variables with special characters

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I've reduced my block of code to the following example. It works when the variable `$backupPath` does not contain a space character, but fails when it does. I've spent a significant amount of time studying the resources below and have tried many variations of the examples there.

I believe that I may need some combination of escape characters and command expansion, perhaps using the `$( )` syntax, but I cannot seem to find the right solution.

**How can I modify this code such that it will work for all possible characters in `$backupPath`?**

```
backupFolderPath=$HOME"/Desktop/folder"
domain=".domain.com";
username="user";
destination[10]="subdomain";
backupPath[10]="/Volumes/backup drive";
i=10    
findCommand[$i]='find '${backupPath[$i]}'  -name "*partfilename*" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f "%m %N" | sort -rn | head -1 | cut -f2- -d" "'
echo ${findCommand[$i]} #looks OK
filePath[$i]=`ssh $username@${destination[$i]}$domain "${findCommand[$i]}"`
echo ${filePath[$i]} # empty when $backupPath contains a space
rsync -avz $username@${destination[$i]}$domain:"${filePath[$i]}" $backupFolderPath # fails when $filePath is empty
```

**Resources:**

[Expansion of variable inside single quotes in a command in bash shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variable-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash-shell-script)

[BASH Script to cd to directory with spaces in pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589149/bash-script-to-cd-to-directory-with-spaces-in-pathname)

[How to input a path with a white space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902227/how-to-input-a-path-with-a-white-space)

[How to set a variable to the output from a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash)

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html

Comment: Potentially using `'findCommand[$i]='find "${backupPath[$i]}" ...` could solve your problem? Note that you have not given us something that we can try..

Comment: It wasn't sufficient to replace the single quotes around `${backupPath[$i]}` with double quotes on the line you suggested. I suppose that it's not possible to create a reproducible example with `ssh`. Is there a way, or is there another command I could try that would fill the same purpose here?

Comment: By the way, is the title of the post OK?

Comment: You should run that code though [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)...

Comment: You need to work on your understanding of how quotes work.  In particular, `backupFolderPath=$HOME"/Desktop/folder"` should be written either `backupFolderPath="$HOME/Desktop/folder"` or `backupFolderPath="$HOME"/Desktop/folder` and you should understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution, remove/replace the 'space' from the path. As you have 'discovered', special chars in file names/paths require special attention and can be quite time consuming to resolve...

Note that you should use double quotes or your variables may not 'expand':

```
"${backupPath[$i]}" ## this should work vs 
'${backupPath[$i]}' ## this should NOT work
```

The OS + Shell combination can make a difference.  Possible solutions might be:

- escape the space i.e. "/Volumes/backup\ drive"
- modify the value of **IFS** (Internal Field Separator); default value is:  [space][tab][newline] == any of these characters will cause a similar issue...  It you take this approach then remember to save, modify + use, and then restore the original value since you could 'break' something else the comes AFTER you tinker with IFS...

:)
Dale