# From string to float with argv in python

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess, args

I can't convert a string passed throug command line to a function to float.

I'll explain better. 
I have this function who takes two arguments, the second one is a float

```
def function():
   first_param = sys.argv[1]
   second_param = float(sys.argv[2])
```

Then I have this other function who calls the first one in a software container

```
def callFunction(first_arg, second_arg):
   cmd = 'docker run --rm -v pathFunction:/home/fenics/shared -w /home/fenics/shared quay.io/fenicsproject/stable "python2 function.py ' + first_arg + str(second_arg)
   process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

When I call:

```
callFunction("some_string",0.02)
```

it returns me an error in function at the line at whick I try the conversione to float saying:
could not convert string to float : shell

UPDATE 
I've found that the problem is that the first string I'm passing is a path with some spaces in it. Something like: 
some_string = C:\blabla\my directory\file.txt" 
with a space between 'my' and 'directory'. I can't change the path, do you know how could I fix it?

Comment: Shouldn't that last line be `process = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, shell=True)`?

Comment: At the end of your `cmd`, `+ first_arg + str(second_arg)` should probably have a space between the args, right?  I imagine you want `some_string 0.02` instead of `some_string0.02`.

Answer (score 3):

```
cmd = 'docker run --rm -v pathFunction:/home/fenics/shared -w /home/fenics/shared quay.io/fenicsproject/stable "python2 function.py ' + first_arg + str(second_arg)
```

You're missing a space between first and second arg. It should be:

```
cmd = 'docker run --rm -v pathFunction:/home/fenics/shared -w /home/fenics/shared quay.io/fenicsproject/stable "python2 function.py ' + first_arg + ' ' + str(second_arg)
```

## edit

as pointed out, you're also missing a ". Here's the way it should be

```
cmd = 'docker run --rm -v pathFunction:/home/fenics/shared -w /home/fenics/shared quay.io/fenicsproject/stable "python2 function.py ' + first_arg + ' ' + str(second_arg) + '"'
```

Comment: And maybe a closing `"`, too?

Comment: The space was not the problem, I've just forgotten to write it here.

Comment: I've found the problem. The first string I'm passing is a path that has some spaces in it (some directory with names like 'my directory'), so the path is splitted throgh the argv. Do you know how could I fix it?

Comment: Escape spaces with \ character. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902227/how-to-input-a-path-with-a-white-space

Answer (score 0):

Change `sys.argv[1]` to `sys.argv[0]` and `sys.argv[1]` to `sys.argv[2]`

```
def function():
   first_param = sys.argv[0]
   second_param = float(sys.argv[1])
```

argument indices start from 0, not from 1.

Check tutorial.[tutorial](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv)

Comment: It doesn't work, it say to me:
can not convert from string to float : method

Comment: This is wrong, sys.argv[0] is always set, and it's the script's name.

Comment: I thought that was the issue because he mentioned callFunction("some_string",0.02) Later saw your answer