# How to export environment variable with space in path on terminal

Tags: java, linux, terminal

I just downloaded Java and according to the Java Control Panel the executable is at this directory:
`/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`

Now I want to export an env variable `JAVA_HOME` as such:

```
>export JAVA_HOME=“/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java”
```

But when I print out the variable everything after the space is butchered

```
>$JAVA_HOME
-bash: “/Library/Internet: No such file or directory
```

How do I properly export this path to the variable?

Now there is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902227/how-to-input-a-path-with-a-white-space) that answers this but that answer there doesn't work:

```
>SOME_PATH="/mnt/someProject/some path"
>$SOME_PATH
-bash: /mnt/someProject/some: No such file or directory
```

And using the other answer on there:

```
>SOME_PATH=/mnt/someProject/some\ path
>$SOME_PATH
-bash: /mnt/someProject/some: No such file or directory
```

And here is my bash version (I'm on macOS 10.14.5):

```
>echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.57(1)-release
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to input a path with a white space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902227/how-to-input-a-path-with-a-white-space)

Comment: I've tried that answer but it doesn't work (see my edit above)

Comment: can you try your original statement but without the " " and escaping space with \ ? Third option of the accepted answer of the question to which I linked.

Comment: If you are doing cd, use eval: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589149/bash-script-to-cd-to-directory-with-spaces-in-pathname

Comment: What will definitely work is `$ export JAVA_HOME="path with spaces"` and then `$ "$JAVA_HOME"` - not sure if you're in a position to do this.

Comment: This is exactly what I have above and it's not working

Comment: It looks like it works right if you place "echo" in front of the env name. not sure why not otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quote and double quote , everything works:

```
[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 ~]$ 
[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 ~]$ 
[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 ~]$ 
[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 ~]$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.4.12(1)-release
[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 ~]$ 
[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 ~]$ export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java"
[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 ~]$ 
[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 ~]$ 
[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 ~]$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java
[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 ~]$ 
[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 ~]$ 
[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 ~]$ export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java'
[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 ~]$ 
[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 ~]$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java
[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 ~]$ 
[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 ~]$
```

Comment: why does it only work when you put 'echo'. Why does it not work right without the echo?

Comment: echo is just to see/confirm the value , it is not needed othervise :) , you script/application will pick the varible anyway

Comment: yeah - but what is the difference between putting "echo" on the terminal line vs not putting it before the env variable to see its value? Forget the script - just from the terminal

Comment: the difference is if you dont put echo on terminal and just write the variable name , shell will not recognise what is that command and throw error

Answer (score 0):

You must use double quote or single quote: the interpreter is seeing “ as any character, thus trying to find a program `“/Library/Internet`.

```
export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java'
```

You don't need to escape anything with single quote, apart from single quote and backslash.

Note that when you are using it directly, like `$JAVA_HOME foobar.Main`, you need to add double quote as well because in that case `$JAVA_HOME` contains space:

```
"$JAVA_HOME" foobar.Main
```

Some terminal might work without double quote, but you should not rely on it.

However, the `JAVA_HOME` is wrong: it should point to a folder which contains `/bin/java`:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_202"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

In that case, you would simply invoke java and your shell would resolve the executable.

Comment: This is certainly not the right answer.  Did you test that? Test what you wrote and then `$JAVA_HOME`

Comment: Explain what don't work, because the other answer was UPVOTED and explain the same. I'm on Windows, not on Mac, and this work although the path is not the same (/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_202). 
And yes, the path should be the stuff before "bin/java", because that what JAVA_HOME should be...

Comment: And yes, when you have a space in $JAVA_HOME, you must quote it when invoking it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the quote mark you used (“) is not the ASCII quote mark (" or ').