# Incorrect path to JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, scala

After running

```
cs install scala
```

scala stopped working on my computer

```
Coursier/bin/scala: line 26: /Library/Internet: No such file or directory
```

Not a surprise because

```
echo $JAVA_HOME 
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

How can I fix the installation?

Comment: Have you tried using the path with a double quoote or an escape char like "\"

Comment: @Ramachandran.A.G sure, here is the relevant line in my .bashrc file `export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home'`

Comment: have you tried
export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home'

Comment: @Ramachandran.A.G Amazing, it worked! Can you please post it as an answer together with short explanation on the possible reasons, especially because of the contrast to the following post https://stackoverflow.com/a/57009614/4954079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escape path for the bashrc in case of spaces is a backslash

```
export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home'
```

Having the backslash negates the space issue that is shown in the execute in the command earlier. It might probably work in the shell with a double-quote (as opposed to the single-quote) , the slash escape seems to work in most cases though!