# What's the best way to convert R path to bash command?

Tags: r, bash, optimization, path, command

I'm trying to launch my R script via ubuntu bash with:

`shell(paste ('bash -c', shQuote(my command string))`

My command string contains two different path in R format: `E:\\path\\path to\\path`, this path must be compatible with bash path format: `/mnt/e/path/path to/path`.
But bash refuse this, removing spaces from path.

What's the easiest way to solve this problem?

Comment: welcome! can you explain why/how the path "must be compatible with the bash path format"? my first thought would be to use R's `file.path()` function to assemble the path in the R command string, but this might not be appropriate for your case?

Comment: I'll try to explain better: i need to run my command string via bash, my command string contains two different path, one for my jar file and one for input files. Actually, to do this task i pass this string to cmd; `bash -c` allows execution via bash (i'm working on WSL). So i need that my path must be identified by bash

Comment: Would this work for you? `gsub('\\\\', '/', yourpath)`

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12902280/8245406)?

Comment: it seems folks are still having a hard time understanding the problem. Perhaps adding some additional detail to your example would help. could you provide an example of `my command string` containing these two paths?