# escape space in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have this workspace and subdirectory:
`$WORKSPACE/Refrens data/11. metadata/file.xml`

in Jenkins section `Execute Shell` we have this code:

```
DEPLOY_FILE=$WORKSPACE/Refrens data/11. metadata/file.xml

if [[ -s $DEPLOY_FILE ]];
   then
    echo "$WORKSPACE/$DEPLOY_FILE exits in Bitbucket"
    echo ""
  else
    echo "$WORKSPACE/$DEPLOY_FILE does not exits in Bitbucket"
    exit 1;
 fi
```

When building it says that this file does not exist and the else part is executed

`$WORKSPACE/Referens data/11. metadata/file.xml does not exist in Bitbucket`

But our file exist!
I think Jenkins does not understand `space` in the directory names `Reference data` and `11. metadata` how do I fix it?

Comment: It is not a Jenkins issue, but rather a shell limitation. Take a look at [how-to-input-a-path-with-a-white-space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902227/how-to-input-a-path-with-a-white-space/12902280)

Comment: @NoamHelmer, yep you're right and this is not Jenkins issue even not shell issue, the problem was with the input file that I had created in Windows.